# Custom font not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load a custom font in my website. In my style.css I have the following attributes declared

```
@font-face {
    font-family: billabong;
    src: url('./fonts/billabong.ttf');
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1.header {
    font-family: billabong;
}
```

And in my html I have the following code;

```
<h1 class="header">Welcome to</h1>
```

However, it seems to be defaulting to some other font type so i assume it cannot find it.

The font is back one directory from my css file, and inside a folder called fonts, have i provided the correct path for it to find it? If this is not the issue does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can try changing the url to '../fonts/billabong.ttf'

Comment: Yup.  `../` means "up one directory" and `./` means the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

try adding Apostrophes in the font-family attribute.

```
font-family: 'billabong';
```

Also use more formats. not all browsers support ttf.
read more about that here:http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/browser-fonts-support-comparison

You could export ttf to webfont here: http://www.font2web.com/

Comment: actually, ttf are [supported by every major browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf).

Comment: I think you mean quotes.  They act as apostrophes too on the keyboard, but technically you place those types of values in quotes.

Comment: that post is from 2012, there should be another good one from 2014.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem here is your directory.

Try first putting your font file all the way up to the same directory as your html file.

Then try this code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: billabong;
    src: url(billabong.ttf);
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1.header {
    font-family: billabong;
}
```

If this doesn't work try putting your font-weight:bold; into the header class see if that helps.

If it works then put it back to where you had it. I hate to guess but as i understand you have a fonts file inside your css file. I am assuming that your html file is one directory higher than your css file. In that case you can say

```
@font-face {
    font-family: billabong;
    src: url(css/fonts/billabong.ttf);
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1.header {
    font-family: billabong;
}
```

You don't need to use apostrophes for your attribute or source url i have made many websites using custom fonts and haven't seen a problem with compatibility and such.

In any case i would always refer to the w3schools website they explain it the best way:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Hopefully that helps.